# Navigation fixed right formatting CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

Im trying to make a responsive design, so I'm trying to make widths based on %

here it is in a jfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1x3whaat/

html

```
<div id="header">

<div id="callout">
Call us : 0123 456 7890
Support : 0123 456 7890
support@website.co.uk

</div>
<div id="logo">
    <a href=""><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo" /></a>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Solutions</a>



        </li>
        <li><a href="">Consultancy</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>   


</nav>


<!-- /header -->
</div>
```

css

```
div#header{
max-width: 1600px;
width: 98%;
position: relative;
background: #ff99ff;

height: 150px;
}

div#header > div#callout {
width: 30%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
background: #99ff99;
font: 4em;
}

div#header > div#logo > a > img {
height: 135px;
}

nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 60%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
background: #066;
}

nav > ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-right: 0;
}

nav > ul > li {
float: left;
border-left: 1px solid #c3b371;
border-right: 1px solid #c3b371;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c3b371;
border-top: none;
width: 13%;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
background: #fcf5d2;
display: block;

font-weight: normal;
font-size: 1em;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #81673d;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
height: 1.5em;
}

nav > ul > li > a:hover, nav > ul > li > a.active, nav > ul > li.active > a {
background-color: #482501;
color: #fff;
}
```

This is an image of how its turned out:
[image: current]

this is an image of what I want it to look like:
[image: want]

Ive tried messing around with floats, padding, margins, changing whether its the nav or ul thats fixed position, and more which I can't remember. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*CSS :*

```
nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 0;
    text-align:right;
    padding:0;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display:inline;
    border-left: 1px solid #c3b371;
    border-right: 1px solid #c3b371;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c3b371;
    border-top: none;
    width: 13%;
}
```

And also remove `display:block;` from `nav > ul > li > a` selector.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1x3whaat/1/)